# How to copy from one column to another column when data is text? (Excel)

Tags: excel, text, copy

!(http://www.hawaiian-holiday.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Untitled.jpg)

here is my situation

I have this database which formatted wrongly. It has some questions(text data) by a certain interval questions are in A1, A7, A13, A19 and so on. I want these questions in B1, B2, B3, and so on.

Similarly I want answer options (text) of a2 in c1, a3 in d1, a4 in e1, a5 in f1, a6 in g1

But a7 data (which is the question) in b2

again a8 in c2, a9 in d2, a10 in e2

How I should do that?

Answer (score 0):

If your information is on Sheet1, then on Sheet 2:

```
A1:  =INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A,(ROWS($1:1)-1)*6+COLUMNS($A:A))
```

Fill right to F1; then select A1:F1 and fill down as far as necessary

To suppress the zero's that will be returned if you fill too far, you can either use custom formatting to suppress the display:

```
;;;@
```

or wrap the above in an IF statement to return a null string:

```
=IF(INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A,(ROWS($1:1)-1)*6+COLUMNS($A:A))=0,"",INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A,(ROWS($1:1)-1)*6+COLUMNS($A:A)))
```

Comment: Thanks this helped me. This is what I wanted. Now those are only formulas. How I get rid of those formula in sheet 2 when I copy?

Comment: @Dinaji Copy/Paste-Special text

Comment: Hi Ron, Thanks a lot. I got it. All my question is answered. It was a great help.

Comment: I have this excel sheet which has some questions. they are in cell no. a1, a2, a3 ....... and so on.

Each question has a number assigned to it like the following.

1. what is your hair color?
2. where is tower hamlet?
3. how to cock 5 potato?
4. Is number 10 greater then number 2?

etc.

You see each question number has a (.) assigned next to it. 

I want to remove any numerical value which has (.) next to it.
so that I have only the text question and not the numbers.

Comment: @Dinaji I would suggest you use `SEARCH` or `FIND` to locate the (.), and then `MID` to remove everything from the start of the line to the (.)